# Adding an image to bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: css, image, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

What would be the best way to add an image to a default navbar dropdown in Bootstrap3. I'd like to recreate the layout in the image below where an image fills to the right of items in the dropdown menu. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** I plan to hide the image on mobile devices for better usability, so I'm only looking to have this layout on desktop.

[image]

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jdda/xg2vs6tj/21/) of where I'm at so far

```
.dropdown-menu {
padding-right: 150px; /* width of img */
position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 150px; /* width of img */
background: url(http://placehold.it/150x220) center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Its Working! See demo Fiddle!**

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fm7fLh4d/3/)

[image: dropdownbs]

---

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown with Image 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="navimg">
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown with Image 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="navimg">
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

---

**css**

```
   .dropdown-menu {
    padding-right: 150px;
    /* width of img */
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
    /* width of img */
    background: url(http://placehold.it/150x220) center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.nav .dropdown-menu ul {
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
.navimg {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Almost! So this works except for the entire navbar expands to accommodate the dropdown. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Perfect - Works like a charm!

Comment: I noticed you link to the image in both the html & css. Is there a reason for the double reference?

Comment: css image was from your code mine was in html :)  its kinda hybrid you can clear code and remove unwanted css

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried targetting parent element **.dropdown-menu:after**,
try to add something like this after Adam's CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu:after < li:nth-child(1){ background: url(1st) center   }
.dropdown-menu:after < li:nth-child(2){ background: url(2nd) center  }
.dropdown-menu:after < li:nth-child(3){ background: url(3rd) center  }
   //etc
```

I haven't tried it out but I think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a bullet-proof example:

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="dropdown"> <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu imaged_menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 fulllist">
            <li><a href="#">Longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more more more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more more more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">More more more more longer menu item</a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 imagebox">
            <img src="http://blog.templatemonster.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Bootstraps.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then **CSS markup:**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
 .imaged_menu {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.imagebox {
    padding:0 2%;
}
.imagebox img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
/* let's hide image ----------- */
 @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .imagebox {
        display:none !important
    }
}
```

As you'll notice with other answers, they all fail at some point because they're trying to use Bootstrap and nothing else, thus suffering on resizing. With this approach, Bootstrap is used only for basic deployment, then we add some minor HTML markup to target the elements accurately, then simply use regular CSS. Try resizing and you'll see how it behaves **EXACTLY** as you asked without major changes needed. And yes, the image disappears when you want.

All this being said, this is some scaffolding basic example, so you'll probably need to adjust some sizes or the media query cue points, but you'll get the idea

Comment: Another great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You'll do this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    padding-right: 100px; /* width of img */
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px; /* width of img */
    background: url(YOUR URL) center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Trick is quite easy. You extend padding of dropdown on right to make space for element, and then you create pseudo element after it with your image.

If you want it to display only on desktop, just wrap it in proper `@media query.`

Comment: You mean you want each dropdown to have different bg? You can use attr(data-image) as css prop value and set it for every .dropdown-menu div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [link to bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dW91qogKin) (**updated**)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>    

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <li><a href="#">Longer menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More longer menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More more longer menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More more more longer menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More more more more longer menu item</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 image .hidden-xs .hidden-sm"> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x220">
    </div>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Add class .hidden-xs and .hidden-sm for not showing in small devices

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    right:0px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:0;
  }

.image img {float:right;}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for menu items with longer string lengths http://www.bootply.com/9eb2ZdCBRo

Comment: @nicogaldo this also works! Question: is a div nested within a ul accepted?